# EF Core 6 Seeding Data Gives Foreign Key error Despite Having FK Value

Tags: entity-framework-core, entity-framework-migrations

So, I have struggled with this for a while now and can't figure out what I'm missing. I have a table that holds an entity called `Skill` and the `DataModel` looks like this:

```
public class SkillModel
{
    public SkillModel()
    {
    }

    public SkillModel(int skillId)
    {
        SkillId = skillId;
    }

    public int SkillId { get; set; } = 0;
    public string Name { get; set; } = "";
    public Guid DescriptionId { get; set; } = new();
    public int SkillGroupId { get; set; } = 0;
    public SkillGroupModel SkillGroup { get; set; } = new();
}
```

It references the `SkillGroup` which is it's own table and it looks like this:

```
public class SkillGroupModel
{
    public SkillGroupModel()
    {
    }

    public SkillGroupModel(int skillGroupId)
    {
        SkillGroupId = skillGroupId;
    }

    public int SkillGroupId { get; set; } = 0;
    public string Name { get; set; } = "";
    public Guid DescriptionId { get; set; } = new();
    public List<SkillModel> Skills { get; set; } = new();
}
```

They each have their own configuration files and the look like this:

SkillModel

```
public class SkillConfiguration : IEntityTypeConfiguration<SkillModel>
{
    public void Configure(EntityTypeBuilder<SkillModel> builder)
    {
        var dataSeeds = new DataSeeds();
        builder.ToTable("Skills", "Skills");
        builder.HasKey(k => k.SkillId);
        builder.HasOne(s => s.SkillGroup)
            .WithMany(s => s.Skills);
        builder.HasData(dataSeeds.Skills);
    }
}
```

SkillGroupModel

```
var dataSeeds = new DataSeeds();
builder.ToTable("SkillGroups", "Skills")
       .HasKey(k => k.SkillGroupId);

builder.HasData(dataSeeds.SkillGroups);
```

Data seeds looks like this:

SkillGroupModel Seed

```
public List<SkillGroupModel> GetSkillGroups()
{
    return new List<SkillGroupModel>()
    {
        new()
        {
            SkillGroupId = 1, Name = "Artisan", DescriptionId = SkillGroupDescriptions["Artisan"].Id
        },
    ...
}
```

SkillModel Seeds

```
return new List<SkillModel>()
    {
        new()
        {
            SkillId = 1,
            Name = "Aesthetics",
            DescriptionId = SkillDescriptions["Aesthetics"].Id,
            SkillGroupId = 1
        },
     ...
}
```

Comment: Remove `= new();` from  `public SkillGroupModel SkillGroup { get; set; } = new();`. **Never** initialize **reference** navigation properties like this, as it would cause many issues (not only data seeding).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So, I was obviously missing something. Ivan Stoev had a great point of not initializing my navigation properties like that, and that was a great help.

I went about it by not using my navigation properties and only setting the FK Properties. I think in the past I was trying to do both and that was causing issues that took me down this path. I'm not sure what I was doing wrong before but the way the documentation for seeding data on MSDN worked fine for me after going back and trying it again.